# Webforms Telerik Radgrid first checked row not being sent to the server

Tags: webforms, telerik, radgrid

I'm having a weird behavior on a Telerik Radgrid control on webforms. I am using checkboxes for allowing the user to select the row(s) he/she wants to remove. The problem is that the first selected row (first one being clicked) is not being sent to the server, i.e if One clicks on three row the second and third ones clicked appear in the [RadgridInstanceName].SelectedValues property

Has anyone had a case like this before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem updating the telerik controls